# Regular expression (.NET): how to get a group in the middle

Tags: .net, regex

I'd like to get a group in the middle. For example:

```
startGOALend => GOAL

GOALend => GOAL

GOAL => GOAL
```

I'm trying `(start)?(.*)(end)?`, but it doesn't lead to needed result.

```
var regex = new Regex("(start)?(.*)(end)?");
if (text == null) return;
var match = regex.Match(text);
foreach (var group in match.Groups)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(group);
}
```

It returns:

```
startGOALend

start

GOALend
```

How could I solve it by regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to avoid capturing the `start` and `end` groups. You can avoid capturing the contents of a pair of parentheses by putting `?:` at the start.

You also need to make the capture of the middle part lazy, so that it doesn't capture `end` as part of the middle part. You can do this by putting a `?` after the `*`.

So altogether, you get:

```
(?:start)?(.*?)(?:end)?$
```